# Formatting good in FireFox, bad in IE.... help

Tags: html, css, firefox, formatting, internet-explorer

I am a newb for sure. I have been developing in the firefox, and just barely checked in IE. Someone please help me out. Don't know where I went wrong. Thanks!

www.clgproperty.com

Comment: Welcome to the world of web "programming".

Comment: That's known as Existential Angst to web developers.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a [strict doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/).

Add this to top of your page (there should be nothing else in front of it, even no whitespace):

```
<!doctype html>
```

This way IE will behave according the [w3 standards](http://www.w3.org/) like as the other (decent and real)  browsers. This must remove the most of the webdev pains, including the [IE box model bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug).

As second step, make use of the [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/). This isn't the holy grail, but this should spot on the [*most*](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.clgproperty.com) of the common problems. When fixing w3 validator problems, do it step by step and retest. Most of the subsequent errors are just "sub-errors" caused by one of the earlier errors.

Good luck. And indeed, welcome at the webdev world :)

Answer (score 1):

1. "Develop your site using Firefox or Opera. Then test it in IE and Chrome
2. Don't do inline styling. Use css files.
3. Continuously check that your design works in these 4 major browsers

Firefox is the best browser for developing websites. Why? Because you can use the FireBug plugin that helps you analyse your html output code and debug javascripts.

Ok, this is all **my** opinion, but it works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the many issues with programming and designing websites.  Different browsers render CSS differently (Some are more standards compliant than others).  Internet Explorer is notorious for being terrible at rendering CSS.

Your only option is to rethink the design and create a new one that works in both browsers from the get-go, or to use Conditional Comments to include specific CSS for a specific browser, such as:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Rather than coding for IE6, tell the user to upgrade their browser. That way, we kind of force the user to upgrade. It's time to look forward, not backward :)

Comment: The conditional statement was just an example, I'm not advocating IE6 specific code.

Comment: IE is only "terrible" at rendering CSS when forced to quirks mode. That's exactly why you need to use the right doctype.